# CakePHP Negated RegEx not working

Tags: php, regex, validation, cakephp, model

I am trying to enforce the first name of my model to be any character but numbers, but so far it's not working as expected.  When I try this:

```
public $validate = array(
    'first_name' => array(
        array(
            'rule' => array('custom', '/^[\d]+/'),
            'message' => 'Please fill in a valid first name'
        )
    )
);
```

it doesn't work because I'm able to save **4** as the name.  If I move the negation to within the brackets like so:

```
public $validate = array(
    'first_name' => array(
        array(
            'rule' => array('custom', '/[^\d]+/'), //allow anything but numbers
            'message' => 'Please fill in a valid first name'
        )
    )
);
```

It also doesn't work because I'm able to save **a4** as the name.  So how can I get best of both worlds without having to include both custom validation rules?

Comment: The `^` metacharacter has two different meanings; 1.) outside a character class it is a zero width assertion (anchor) meaning: _"start of string/line"_,  2.) inside a character class, (if its the very first character), it negates the char class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/^[^\d]+$/` allows anything but numbers

Comment: @paulsmith - Yes, otherwise it would allow non-digit character(s) to be followed by anything...